# Is a Shift Cipher with Random Insertions Unbreakable?

Tags: cryptanalysis, symmetric, substitution-cipher, frequency-analysis

Imagine an **Encryption Algorithm** which applies a classic **Shift Cipher** (also called *Caesar* or *ROT-X*) to a text (with only lowercase `[a-z]` and the space `' '` character), but has one parameter `r` (randomness) to decide if in each round/iteration attempting to encrypt one char `c`, it encrypts the character `c+key`, or if it inserts a completely random character `rchar` and repeats next iteration with the same non-encrypted yet character `c`.

For example, with a plaintext `ptext=hello`, `r=0.20`, and `key=1`, the encryption algorithm will output `ctext=ifrmmp` where every char was shifted by `1` position but **1 new random character** was added (since 20% is 1 of each 5, and `hello` has 5 chars, I assume only one time the condition of adding a random char was `true`).

Now imagine that you have a dictionary `dict` of `U=10` plaintexts of length `L=500`, and you need to decide, from a ciphertext input `ctext`, which one of the plaintext `ptext` from the dictionary `dict` corresponds to the given ciphertext.

A regular approach would be to do **Frequency Analysis**, but with a high value of `r` (>10/15 %) the results are not consistent.

Is this encryption algorithm unbreakable? Or is there a way to consistently guess the correct plaintext?

Answer (score 3):

Frequency analysis would still apply albeit larger quantities of ciphertext might be required.

If your system is to introduce a random character with probability $p$ and the plaintext frequency of a given letter is $q$, then the ciphertext frequency of its shift will be $(1-p)q+p/26$ and if $q\neq 1/26$ this is still distinguishable from uniform. In particular, common letter will continue to have a frequency above 1/26 and uncommon letters a frequency below 1/26.

There is the added complication that it is not clear that you system is able to be decrypted unambiguously. How should I interpret a message that after unshifting reads `ICATNOFFENRYOUSOMEVICEWICTHYOURGINABNDTONXIC`?

If there is a systematic way to determine which characters are random inserts, then this is an example of a [null cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_cipher).